# How to animate multiple sets of XY data

Tags: plotting, dynamic, fluid-dynamics

I have nine sets of data with $(x,y)$ coordinates that are the position of a particle. I can `ListPlot` the particle positions on a single plot, but, I want to animate this.

```
ListPlot[
{mydata1, mydata2, mydata3, mydata4, mydata5, mydata6, 
  mydata7, mydata8, mydata9}
, PlotRange -> {{-1, 20}, {-1, 20}}
]
```

I have been playing around with `ListAnimate` and I can get one particle to animate but I can not get the rest.

```
ListAnimate[
 ListPlot[{#, #}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 20}, {-1, 20}}] & /@ mydata1
]
```

Is there a way to get all nine particles in the same frame?

```
mydata1 := {{5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {4.5, 4.5}} 
mydata2 := {{10, 5}, {11, 6}, {13, 7}, {14, 8}, {12, 4.5}} 
mydata3 := {{15, 5}, {16, 6}, {17, 7}, {19, 8}, {20, 4.5}} 
mydata4 := {{5, 10}, {6, 11}, {7, 12}, {8, 13}, {5, 10}} 
mydata5 := {{10, 10}, {11, 11}, {14, 12}, {19, 13}, {11, 10}} 
mydata6 := {{15, 10}, {16, 11}, {17, 12}, {18, 13}, {17, 10}} 
mydata7 := {{5, 15}, {6, 16}, {7, 17}, {8, 18}, {7, 16}} 
mydata8 := {{10, 15}, {11, 16}, {15, 17}, {13, 18}, {9, 16}} 
mydata9 := {{15, 15}, {16, 16}, {17, 17}, {12, 18}, {8, 16}}
```

Comment: Welcome! Adding some actual sample data to the question avoids overhead and misunderstandings on our side. Just a hint: Your problem might benefit from `Part` and `Span` together with `Tableb` or `MapIndexed`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I haven't used Part and Span so I'm not sure how that would work? In any case, I have a 1000 data points in each data set so I could just put up a simple data set just to get the format down.

Comment: mydata1 := {{5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {4.5, 4.5}}
mydata2 := {{10, 5}, {11, 6}, {13, 7}, {14, 8}, {12, 4.5}}
mydata3 := {{15, 5}, {16, 6}, {17, 7}, {19, 8}, {20, 4.5}}
mydata4 := {{5, 10}, {6, 11}, {7, 12}, {8, 13}, {5, 10}}
mydata5 := {{10, 10}, {11, 11}, {14, 12}, {19, 13}, {11, 10}}
mydata6 := {{15, 10}, {16, 11}, {17, 12}, {18, 13}, {17, 10}}
mydata7 := {{5, 15}, {6, 16}, {7, 17}, {8, 18}, {7, 16}}
mydata8 := {{10, 15}, {11, 16}, {15, 17}, {13, 18}, {9, 16}}
mydata9 := {{15, 15}, {16, 16}, {17, 17}, {12, 18}, {8, 16}}

Comment: A small sample is just fine. Now please edit those lines into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data, in a single block

```
data = {
   {{5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {4.5, 4.5}}
   , {{10, 5}, {11, 6}, {13, 7}, {14, 8}, {12, 4.5}}
   , {{15, 5}, {16, 6}, {17, 7}, {19, 8}, {20, 4.5}}
   , {{5, 10}, {6, 11}, {7, 12}, {8, 13}, {5, 10}}
   , {{10, 10}, {11, 11}, {14, 12}, {19, 13}, {11, 10}}
   , {{15, 10}, {16, 11}, {17, 12}, {18, 13}, {17, 10}}
   , {{5, 15}, {6, 16}, {7, 17}, {8, 18}, {7, 16}}
   , {{10, 15}, {11, 16}, {15, 17}, {13, 18}, {9, 16}}
   , {{15, 15}, {16, 16}, {17, 17}, {12, 18}, {8, 16}}
   };
```

Now the animation

```
Animate[
 ListPlot[data[[k]], PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}]
 , {k, 1, 9, 1}
 ]
```

shorter than

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[
  ListPlot[data[[k]], PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}]
  , {k, 1, 9, 1}
  ]]
```

but same result.

You can export by

```
Export["Q96726.GIF", Table[
  ListPlot[data[[k]], PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}]
  , {k, 1, 9, 1}
  ]]
```

[image]

Comment: I only see five or six particles on that gif?

Comment: 5, as many as the points in each data set you offered.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhh. Then this is transposed. I want nine points with five xy positions.

Comment: Then just use `Transpose`

Answer (score 2):

```
mydata1 := {{5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {4.5, 4.5}}
mydata2 := {{10, 5}, {11, 6}, {13, 7}, {14, 8}, {12, 4.5}}
mydata3 := {{15, 5}, {16, 6}, {17, 7}, {19, 8}, {20, 4.5}}
mydata4 := {{5, 10}, {6, 11}, {7, 12}, {8, 13}, {5, 10}}
mydata5 := {{10, 10}, {11, 11}, {14, 12}, {19, 13}, {11, 10}}
mydata6 := {{15, 10}, {16, 11}, {17, 12}, {18, 13}, {17, 10}}
mydata7 := {{5, 15}, {6, 16}, {7, 17}, {8, 18}, {7, 16}}
mydata8 := {{10, 15}, {11, 16}, {15, 17}, {13, 18}, {9, 16}}
mydata9 := {{15, 15}, {16, 16}, {17, 17}, {12, 18}, {8, 16}}

data = Table[
    ToExpression["mydata" <> ToString[n]],
    {n, 9}] // Transpose;

Animate[ListPlot[List /@ data[[n]],
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 21}, {-1, 21}},
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> Range[Length[data[[1]]]]],
 {n, 1, Length[data], 1}]
```